# how can i force device to load content in landscape mode in jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery, mobile, cordova

I have developed an app using phone gap and "J query" mobile.
I have a table which contains more than 13 columns,and it is not fit in portrait mode,so i need to display table in landscape mode.
Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot easily switch between portrait and landscape, but you can force one or the other with this in your config.xml:

```
<preference name="orientation" value="landscape" />
```